# Only run HTML (PHP)

Tags: php, html, xss

I'm here with a question on a project; I try to explain as best as possible:

I have a text area in which the user can write whatever they want.
The problem is that they can try for some kind of malicious code (js xss, for example)
I was using the function:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($topic->getMessage(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I thought I had solved the problem, but I remembered that the user can type HTML, and it is allowed.

Is there any function already made for running HTML and others stay as text?

Comment: So you want to allow certain HTML elements/attributes, but filter out anything else? No, there is no build-in function for that, but there’s external tools/libraries, such as f.e. http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @CBroe tks, solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlspecialchars is ok but not completely safe to insert into mysql.

For mysql it's better to use prepared statements, such as explained here:
http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

For output in the page (without inserting on database), htmlspecialchars is enough... provided you don't decode those before printing.

Like CBroe suggested, You could use `http://htmlpurifier.org/` to clean the html and avoid garbage in your database, but you still must use prepared statements.

Also read: `http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php`

Answer (score 3):

As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), `htmlspecialchars` performs the following translations:

> `'&'` (ampersand) becomes `'&amp;'`
>
> `'"'` (double quote) becomes `'&quot;'` when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
>
> `"'"` (single quote) becomes `'&#039;'` (or `&apos;`) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
>
> `'<'` (less than) becomes `'&lt;'`
>
> `'>'` (greater than) becomes `'&gt;'`

Your HTML actually does get translated into safe characters.

After reading your question again (for it's not very clear), I thought maybe you want the HTML tags actually stay as HTML tags, meaning `<b>bold</b>` wouldn't get translated into `&lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;`

To do so, you may want to use `str_replace` after `htmlspecialchars`:

```
$result = htmlspecialchars($topic->getMessage(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$result = str_replace(array("&lt;","&gt;"), array("<",">"), $result);
echo $result;
```

Or you could just translate `&`, `'` (single quote) and `"` (double quote) via `str_replace`:

```
echo str_replace(array("&", "\"", "'"), array("&amp;", "&quot;", "&#039;"), $topic->getMessage());
```

Possibilities are endless.